# recyclerview сделать таймер в каждом элементе списка

Tags: java, android

Необходимо написать приложение в котором элементы помещены в `RecyclerView`. Каждый элемент имеет кнопку запуска и остановки `CountDownTimer`, который обновляет состояние времени в каждом элементе списка. Проблема состоит в том, что если прокрутить список, а потом перейти на другую активность, то при возвращении к активности c `RecyclerView` строка содержащая время пропадает, а таймер доходит до конца в фоне и после этого начинает сигнализировать. Кнопки теряют связь с порожденным потоком и не могут остановить таймер. Может у кого есть пример написания подобного `RecyclerView`'а?

```
private class ScooterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

    private Scooter mScooter;

    private TextView mTitleTextView,mDateTextView, mTextViewTarif,mTextViewStatus,mTextViewSum;
    private ToggleButton mToggleButtonStart,mToggleButtonPaid;
    private RelativeLayout mRelativeLayout;
    private EditText mEditTextTime;

    private CountDownTimer timer;
    private Timer mTimer;
    private MyTimerTask mMyTimerTask;


    public ScooterHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTitleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_title_text_view);
        mDateTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_date_text_view);
        mTextViewTarif=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_tarif_text_view);
        mTextViewStatus=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_status_text_view);
        mTextViewSum=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_sum_text_view);
        mToggleButtonStart=(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_start_toggle_button);
        mToggleButtonPaid=(ToggleButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_paid_toggle_button);
        mRelativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_layout);
        mEditTextTime=(EditText)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scooter_edit_text_time);

        mToggleButtonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        mToggleButtonPaid.setOnClickListener(this);
        mTitleTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);

    }

    public void bindScooter(Scooter scooter) {
        mScooter = scooter;
        mTitleTextView.setText("Скутер №"+mScooter.getTitle());
        mTextViewTarif.setText("Тариф: "+mScooter.getTarif());
        mTextViewStatus.setText("Статус скутера: "+mScooter.getStatus());

        mEditTextTime.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
                switch (result) {
                    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
                        mScooter.setDate((Long.valueOf(v.getText().toString())*60*1000));
                        mTextViewSum.setText("Сумма к оплате: "+((Double.valueOf(v.getText().toString()))*mScooter.getSum())+" руб.");
                        mEditTextTime.setText(v.getText().toString()+" мин");
                        ScooterLab.get(getActivity()).updateScooter(mScooter);
                        InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        if (mScooter.isPaid()==true){
            mToggleButtonPaid.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            mToggleButtonPaid.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            mToggleButtonPaid.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        if (mScooter.isStart()==true){
            mToggleButtonStart.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            mToggleButtonStart.setChecked(true);
        }else {
            mToggleButtonStart.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        if (mScooter.getStatus().equals("Свободен")){
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_free));
            mToggleButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
            mToggleButtonPaid.setEnabled(true);
        }else if(mScooter.getStatus().equals("Работает")){
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
            mToggleButtonStart.setEnabled(true);
            mToggleButtonPaid.setEnabled(true);
        }else {
            mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_charging));
            mToggleButtonStart.setEnabled(false);
            mToggleButtonPaid.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.list_item_scooter_title_text_view:
                Intent intent=ScooterActivity.newIntent(getActivity(),mScooter.getId());
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.list_item_scooter_paid_toggle_button:
                if (mToggleButtonPaid.isChecked()==true){
                    mToggleButtonPaid.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mScooter.setPaid(true);
                }else {
                    mToggleButtonPaid.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    mScooter.setPaid(false);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.list_item_scooter_start_toggle_button:
                if (mToggleButtonStart.isChecked()==true){
                    mToggleButtonStart.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    mScooter.setStart(true);
                    mScooter.setStatus("Работает");
                    mTextViewStatus.setText("Статус скутера: "+mScooter.getStatus());
                    showTimer(10000);
                }else {
                    mToggleButtonStart.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                    mRelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_free));
                    mScooter.setStart(false);
                    mScooter.setStatus("Свободен");
                    mTextViewStatus.setText("Статус скутера: "+mScooter.getStatus());
                    mScooter.setDate(0);
                    //timerStart(2);
                    if(mTimer!=null){
                        timerStart(2);
                        mTimer=null;
                    }
                    if(timer!=null){
                        timer.cancel();
                        timer=null;
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        ScooterLab.get(getActivity()).updateScooter(mScooter);
    }

    //таймер отсчета времени
    public void showTimer(long countdownMillis) {
        if(timer != null) { timer.cancel(); }
        timer = new CountDownTimer(countdownMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mDateTextView.setText("Осталось "+String.format("%d мин %d сек",
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes( millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));
                mScooter.setDate(millisUntilFinished);
                ScooterLab.get(getActivity()).updateScooter(mScooter);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mDateTextView.setText("Время вышло!");
                String text = "Скутер №"+mScooter.getTitle()+" завершил работу";
                mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                timerStart(1);
            }
        }.start();
    }


    //таймер для повторного воспроизведения озвучки
    private void timerStart(int i) {
        if(mTimer != null) { mTimer.cancel(); }
        if (i == 1) {
            mTimer = new Timer();
            mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
            // delay 1000ms, repeat in 5000ms
            mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 1000, 5000);
        } else {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String text = "Скутер №" + mScooter.getTitle() + " завершил работу";
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                    }
                });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    //озвучка
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            Locale locale = new Locale("ru");

            int result = mTTS.setLanguage(locale);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Извините, этот язык не поддерживается");
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Ошибка!");
        }
    }
}

private class ScooterAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ScooterHolder> {

    private List<Scooter> mScooters;

    public ScooterAdapter(List<Scooter> scooters) {
        mScooters = scooters;
    }

    @Override
    public ScooterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_scooter, parent, false);
        return new ScooterHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ScooterHolder holder, int position) {
        Scooter scooter = mScooters.get(position);
        holder.bindScooter(scooter);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mScooters.size();
    }

    public void setScooters(List<Scooter> scooters) {
        mScooters= scooters;
    }
}
```

Comment: примера нет ни у кого. Проблема в вашем коде. На вон той строчке. Нет, не той, а следующей. Так понятно?

Comment: Пока по вашему вопросу можно сказать, что вам скорее всего надо как минимум использовать сервис, если вы хотите, чтобы ваше приложение работало не зависимо от Activity

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в методе `OnResume()`, в котором осуществлялось обновление адаптера. Обновлялся весь список целиком при изменении элемента, переписал на обновление конкретной позиции и все стало работать.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что данные таймера необходимо хранить не в элементе, а в массиве.
Например, есть некий массив времён по количеству позиций.

```
long[] times = new long[*количество*]; //можно использовать гибкий ArrayList
```

При создании элемента мы просто записываем в него нужное нам время -

```
times[position] = new Date().getTime();
```

В самом элементе, в методе getView() ваш "счётчик" просто рассчитывает и отображает время, в нужном вам формате, от сохранённой в массиве. 
showTimer(times[position]);

Таким образом, данные всегда будут корректны.